# Download google docs public spreadsheet to csv with python

Tags: python, google-sheets

I can download a CSV file from Google Docs with `wget`:

```
wget --no-check-certificate --output-document=locations.csv 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArM5yzzCw9IZdEdLWlpHT1FCcUpYQ2RjWmZYWmNwbXc&output=csv'
```

But I can't download the same csv with Python:

```
import urllib2

request = urllib2.Request('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArM5yzzCw9IZdEdLWlpHT1FCcUpYQ2RjWmZYWmNwbXc&output=csv')
request.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1284.0 Safari/537.13')
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
data = opener.open(request).read()
print(data)
```

The result is the Google login page. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just use [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io), it is way better than using urllib:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArM5yzzCw9IZdEdLWlpHT1FCcUpYQ2RjWmZYWmNwbXc&output=csv')
assert response.status_code == 200, 'Wrong status code'
print(response.content)
```

You can install it with

```
pip install requests
```

Comment: nitpick: You should use `response.raise_for_status()` instead of asserting `response.status_code == 200` for the simple reason that `assert` statements are stripped out when python is run with optimization flags.

Comment: That was just for explanation, if you deploy code with python optimize, all asserts will be stripped.

Comment: Hey @JaysonReis, is there an option to choose which sheet your need. And also when you do specify only the `&output=csv' are you getting only one or all of them?

Comment: Did not work for me. I had to use `'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArM5yzzCw9IZdEdLWlpHT1FCcUpYQ2RjWmZYWmNwbXc/export?format=csv'`

Comment: These URLs likely changed over the years, it is better if you checkout google doc's API and maybe use some library that already implements those functionalities.

Answer (score 12):

**You're not storing cookies.**

First let me say that I completely endorse the recommendation to use the [most-excellent `requests` library](http://docs.python-requests.org/).

However, if you need to do this in vanilla Python 2, the problem lies in the fact that Google is bouncing you around via HTTP 302 redirects, and it expects you to remember the cookies it's setting with each response.  When it detects that you aren't storing cookies, it redirects you to the login page.

By default, `urllib2.urlopen` (or the opener returned from `build_opener`) will follow 302 redirects, but it won't store HTTP cookies.  You have to teach your opener how to do that.  Like so:

```
>>> from cookielib import CookieJar
>>> from urllib2 import build_opener, HTTPCookieProcessor
>>> opener = build_opener(HTTPCookieProcessor(CookieJar()))
>>> resp = opener.open('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArM5yzzCw9IZdEdLWlpHT1FCcUpYQ2RjWmZYWmNwbXc&output=csv')
>>> data = resp.read()
```

Again, use `requests` if at all possible, but if it's not possible, the standard library can get the job done.

Comment: +1 for providing plain-vanilla python 2 solution. Not everyone necessarily has the ability or authorization to just install new libraries.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't get any simpler than using `Pandas`:

```
def build_sheet_url(doc_id, sheet_id):
    return f'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{doc_id}/export?format=csv&gid={sheet_id}'

def write_df_to_local(df, file_path):
    df.to_csv(file_path)

doc_id = 'DOC_ID'
sheet_id = 'SHEET_ID'
sheet_url = build_sheet_url(doc_id, sheet_id)
df = pd.read_csv(sheet_url)
file_path = 'FILE_PATH'
write_df_to_local(df, file_path)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `requests` library is great and the gold standard for HTTP requests from Python, however this style of download is, while not deprecated yet, not likely to last, specifically referring to the download-link style. In fact, the `downloadUrl` field in the [Google Drive API v2](http://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/) is [already deprecated](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/v2-to-v3-reference#resource_field_differences_between_v2_and_v3). The currently accepted way of exporting Google Sheets as CSV is by *using* the (current) [Google Drive API](http://developers.google.com/drive).

So why the Drive API? Isn't this supposed to be something for the [Sheets API](http://developers.google.com/sheets) instead? Well, the Sheets API is for **spreadsheet**-oriented functionality, i.e., data formatting, column resize, creating charts, cell validation, etc., while the Drive API is for **file**-oriented functionality, i.e., import/export.

Below is a [complete cmd-line solution](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/07/exporting-google-sheet--as-csv.html). (If you don't do Python, you can use it as pseudocode and pick any language supported by the [Google APIs Client Libraries](http://developers.google.com/discovery/libraries).) For the code snippet, assume the most current Sheet named `inventory` (older files with that name are ignored) and `DRIVE` is the API service endpoint:

```
FILENAME = 'inventory'
SRC_MIMETYPE = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'
DST_MIMETYPE = 'text/csv'

# query for latest file named FILENAME
files = DRIVE.files().list(
    q='name="%s" and mimeType="%s"' % (FILENAME, SRC_MIMETYPE),
    orderBy='modifiedTime desc,name').execute().get('files', [])

# if found, export 1st matching Sheets file as CSV
if files:
    fn = '%s.csv' % os.path.splitext(files[0]['name'].replace(' ', '_'))[0]
    print('Exporting "%s" as "%s"... ' % (files[0]['name'], fn), end='')
    data = DRIVE.files().export(fileId=files[0]['id'], mimeType=DST_MIMETYPE).execute()

    # if non-empty file
    if data:
        with open(fn, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(data)
        print('DONE')
```

If your Sheet is large, you may have to export it in chunks -- see [this page](http://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents) on how to do *that*. If you're generally new to Google APIs, I have a (somewhat dated but) user-friendly [intro video](http://youtu.be/DYAwYxVs2TI?list=PLOU2XLYxmsILOIxBRPPhgYbuSslr50KVq&index=2) for you. (There are 2 videos after that maybe useful too.)

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12842633/20292589) in 2024, API endpoint is changed.
Currently it has format `{google_doc}/export?format=csv`

```py
import requests

response = requests.get(r"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10X0-CCSv7FenZP1YaKlDSE-PD4LSZAgpzT5Rs9F8hvA/export?format=csv")
print(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

i would use requests

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArM5yzzCw9IZdEdLWlpHT1FCcUpYQ2RjWmZYWmNwbXc&output=csv')
data = r.content
```

Answer (score 0):

must need requests lib --> pip install requests

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import requests

link = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11D0KAvm_ERXZ3XMgft5DM19IREaNvGargPlvW8e2DXg/edit#gid=0"
domain = urlparse(link).netloc
segments = link.rpartition('/')
link = segments[0] + "/export?format=csv"
file = requests.get(link)
if file.status_code == 200:
    fileContent = file.content.decode('utf-8')
    print(fileContent)
```