# How do I read a google spreadsheet in python using key, without signing in?

Tags: python, google-sheets

I have used the `gspread` library to read a CSV file from Google docs but it first requires me to log in.

```
gc = gspread.login('email','password')
sheetData = gc.open("NSEport").sheet1
```

I want to directly open a spreadsheet using the key generated when we shared the spreadsheet, without logging in to a Google account.

Comment: i have found the answer on stackoverflow link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842341/download-google-docs-public-spreadsheet-to-csv-with-python.  but the problem is how to access the sheets in the spreadsheet

Answer (score 1):

```
full_doc = gc.open("NSEport")
list_of_worksheets = full_doc.worksheets()
one_I_want = full_doc.get_worksheet(0)  # gets first worksheet
```