# Download a google sheets as a csv

Tags: javascript, npm, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am working on creating cloud functions to push data to Google AutoML. I have a function to create the data. For the next step, I am wondering. In a cloud function, is it possible to download a google sheets as a csv to a temp directory after data had populated it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is possible. You can check this SO answer about :

[Download google docs public spreadsheet to csv with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842341/download-google-docs-public-spreadsheet-to-csv-with-python)

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArM5yzzCw9IZdEdLWlpHT1FCcUpYQ2RjWmZYWmNwbXc&output=csv')
assert response.status_code == 200, 'Wrong status code'
print(response.content)
```

Then you can save the `respose.content` to a file to `/tmp` directory

[Cloud Functions Execution Environment](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec)

> The only writeable part of the filesystem is the /tmp directory, which
> you can use to store temporary files in a function instance. This is a
> local disk mount point known as a "tmpfs" volume in which data written
> to the volume is stored in memory. Note that it will consume memory
> resources provisioned for the function.
>
> The rest of the file system is read-only and accessible to the
> function.