# I'm still learning A.I and trying to create a Linear Regression algorithm model, but I keep getting KeyError when trying to pop a column

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I'm learning from a python course from tech by tim, I used his code for a basic Linear Regression algorithm and tried to make my own small data sheet to try it out, whenever I import my data sheet it shows the following error:

```
KeyError: 'xvalue'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:
-> 2900                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2901 
   2902         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'xvalue'
```

my code is as follows:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import clear_output
from six.moves import urllib

import tensorflow.compat.v2.feature_column as fc

import tensorflow as tf
# Load dataset.
train = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qQfNL2ePWVsOiqSNgJu_ZwmI9KFwFTrtdb1boqIKFZQ/edit?usp=sharing"
eval = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ip1Key9NYx3boTUFkPUOzEWdtUBMeGJJEY3MbSpVkUo/edit?usp=sharing"
dftrain = pd.read_csv(train, sep='\t,\s*') # training data
dfeval = pd.read_csv(eval, sep='\t,\s*') # testing data
y_train = dftrain.pop('xvalue')
y_eval = dfeval.pop('xvalue')
```

I'm using the google python notebook to code this, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When I run this script, the `dftrain` variable does not contain the CSV. It instead contains an error page that I don't have permission to load the CSV. Do you have access to https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qQfNL2ePWVsOiqSNgJu_ZwmI9KFwFTrtdb1boqIKFZQ/edit?usp=sharing ?

Comment: Yah I'm certain that I have it accessible to everyone

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to export the contents of a Google Sheets spreadsheet, you can use the suggestion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842341/download-google-docs-public-spreadsheet-to-csv-with-python/12842633#12842633).

In your case, you're using Pandas, so you don't need to use the `requests` package.

So you can define this function:

```py
def get_docs_url(doc_id):
    url = f"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key={doc_id}&output=csv"
    return url
```

And use it like this:

```
train = get_docs_url('1qQfNL2ePWVsOiqSNgJu_ZwmI9KFwFTrtdb1boqIKFZQ')
dftrain = pd.read_csv(train) # training data
```

PS: I removed the `sep='\t,\s*'` part because it's not needed to parse a CSV file.

PPS: The test dataset has different column names than the train dataset. I needed to add `dfeval = dfeval.rename(columns={'X': 'xvalue', 'Y': 'yvalue'})` to get it to work.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked for me, and about the different names, I was trying other names trying to figure out if it was the problem, But seriously thank you so much for your help!